# [ROS2] TF2 broadcasting very slow

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a node that broadcasts dynamic TF2 transforms (30 Hz ) and a `robot_state_publisher` that broadcasts the static TF2 from an URDF file.

The problem is that in Rviz I notice a very slow propagation of the Transforms and using the command `ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo` I indeed receive TF2 at about 1Hz that is a really low frequency.

For many links the TF propagation cannot be calculated at all.

What can be the problem?

Thank you
Walter

**UPDATE**
I noticed that the command works well for "static frames" but cannot connect "static frames" to "dynamic frames".

Considering the TF chain:

```
zed_left_camera_frame -> zed_camera_center -> base_link -> odom -> map
```

if I run the command `$ ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_monitor zed_left_camera_frame map`
I get this broken chain:

```
ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_monitor zed_left_camera_frame map
Waiting for transform chain to become available between zed_left_camera_frame and map 



RESULTS: for zed_left_camera_frame to map
Chain is: zed_left_camera_frame -> zed_camera_center -> base_link
Net delay     avg = 0.00394501: max = 0.0212562

Frames:
Frame: base_link, published by <no authority available>, Average Delay: 0.0107858, Max Delay: 0.0123577

All Broadcasters:
Node: <no authority available> 61.1384 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0105982 Max Delay: 0.0123577
```

It seems that the remaining chain `base_link -> odom -> map` cannot be resolved and I cannot find the reason.

The weird thing is that `$ ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo zed_left_camera_frame map 30` gives a correct result

How can I understand the cause of the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303377/%5Bros2%5D-tf2-broadcasting-very-slow/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an issue with incoming queue processing in rviz that sounds similar to your problem recently fixed here: https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/354

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-18**:
I updated my ROS2 sources to latest `master`, but I continue to see latency in TF propagation in Rviz2 and furthermore when trying to get a transform from a static frame to a dynamic frame it is not available even if I can see it using the `tf2_echo` command